# Application updates in emulator from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse, when I modify my Android application and I launch it in the emulator, Eclipse first asks me if I want to save the modified files and I answer "yes". So far, everything seems normal.

The problem is that, in the console window, Eclipse says : "Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.". And the application is not updated in the emulator.

Any idea of a reason which could explain this behaviour?

I can add that the "Build automatically" option is set.

After some more investigations, despite the "Build automatically" option set, I'm not sure the build is executed. How can I check if a new "apk" file has been created?

The problem seems to be much bigger : when I create with the wizard a brand new Android application, in the error window, Eclipse displays the following error : "failed to load properties files for project". The resource file (R) is not generated and, in the marker window, I have one error for each line of code containing a reference to the resource file.

With a complete re-installation of both Eclipse and the Android SDK manager, the problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the app.
Also, always exit the app in the emulator before updating it. It should work by itself, but it can be weird sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the application in your emulator and red-deploy it.